# Laravel General error: 1005 Can't create table

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, migration, laravel-migrations

I get this error when I do php artisan migrate. Is there something wrong in my migration files?

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Can't create table `test`.`blog_posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
>   constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `blog_posts` add
>   constraint `blog_pos ts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`)
>   references `users` (`id`))

**blog_posts**

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('cаtegory_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('excerpt')->nullable(); դաշտ չի
        $table->text('content_raw');
        $table->text('content_html');
        $table->boolean('is_published')->default(false);
        $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes(); 
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('cаtegory_id')->references('id')->on('blog_categories');
        $table->index('is_published');
```

**blog_categories**

```
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(0); 
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('description')->unllable(); 
    $table->timestamps(); 
    $table->softDeletes();
```

**users**

```
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match the column type and format from the users table into the FK.  But you first need to actually create the column on the `blog_posts` table from which to draw the FK to *match exactly what you have on the users table*:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

is the FK instruction, but before this, you need to add the actual column to match the users table.  Nullable is optional, depending on how you want to proceed:

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```